# Collection python coverage with a tcsh wrapper

Tags: python, code-coverage, tcsh, coverage.py

I have a python script that being run by a wrapper that is written in tcsh. I'm trying to use the Python Coverage.py module in order to collect coverage of the python script. I tried:

```
coverage run wrapper
```

But the problem is that the wrapper is written in tcsh and not in python so it fails to collect data. Unfortunately, I can't edit the wrapper. Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: You are usually collecting coverage data while running tests. So, what testing framework to you use?

Comment: No testing framework, just a script that runs the script in shell and collects coverage.

Comment: "coverage" is short for "test coverage", the number of code lines executed by running automated tests. So what kind of "coverage" are you measuring?

Comment: @KlausD. Just line coverage (What coverage.py gives us)

Comment: @KlausD. You can measure coverage without tests being involved.

Answer (score 0):

Coverage.py doesn't understand shell wrappers. You need to change the wrapper so that instead of "python your_program.py" it runs "coverage run your_program.py".

You can also try following the instructions for sub-process measurement here: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.0.3/subprocess.html#configuring-python-for-sub-process-coverage